# Regarding an integrability property of Schwartz class function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R^n})$, Schwartz class, satisfying
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x)|e^{g(||x||)}dx<\infty,  $$
where $g:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be an increasing function satisfying $\int_0^\infty\frac{g(r)}{1+r^2}dr=\infty.$

Is it always true that for any polynomial $P_1$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and any polynomial $P_2$ on $S^{n-1}$, we must have
$$\int_0^\infty\int_{S^{n-1}}|f(rw)P_1(r)P_2(w)|e^{g(r)}drd\sigma(w)<\infty?  $$
($d\sigma$ is the normalised surface measure of $S^{n-1}$)

Comment: Now I am thinking that Cauchy-Schwartz may be helpful. Have to work with $h=g/2$. But can't write it properly because of $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Comment: What am I missing - why can one not take for example $f$ to be something like $x \mapsto \lvert x \rvert^{-n-1} e^{-g(x)}$, suitably cut off near the origin?

Comment: I think that this is essentailly a one-dimensional question, i.e., you have to understand if the class of Schwartz funtions with $\int_0^\infty |f(r)|e^{g(r)}dr <\infty$ is stable under multiplication with $r$. Such conditions appear in the study of *ultradifferentiable* functions, e.g. by Björk or Braun, Meise, and Taylor.

Comment: This is false, for example $g(r)=r^2$, $f(x)=e^{-r^2}/(1+r^2)$.